# data transmission between two sites

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm use Asp.Net Mvc 4
www.hostname.com to my site from my report.hostname2.com
send and receive data to move directly to that address by the string bi codebehind.
querysstring not, because sending a very long string

I mean rapor.coskunoglu.net/Pdf address to send string data to move directly to
that address
PDF of the screen to make it appear so.

How can I do this?
Thank you, take it easy.

I'm sorry, my english is not good.

---

**EDIT0:**
I want to use POST.
 sb -> my StringBuilder.

```
byte[] bytt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());   
 WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://report.hostname2.com/Pdf");   
 wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";   
 wr.ContentLength = bytt.Length;   
 wr.Method = "POST";   
 Stream st = wr.GetRequestStream();   
 st.Write(bytt, 0, bytt.Length);   
 st.Close();
```

After you send the POST I want to go to report.hostname2.com.
Did you see this my job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to store the data you want to transmit into some commonly shared database between the two sites and then simply send an id to the other site as a query string so that it could retrieve the data. If you cannot use a shared database then all that's left is standard HTTP protocol means:

- GET - query string - impractical in your case if the data is large
- POST - generate a form and then submit this form to the remote site - could be a good solution for your case because you are not limited in size

Alternatively you could use a WebClient to POST some data:

```
StringBuilder sb = ... the data to send

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "data", sb.ToString() }
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://report.hostname2.com/Pdf", values);
}
```

And then on the remote site you could read the `data` POST parameter from the request.

Comment: I want to use POST.

 byte[] bytt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());   
 WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://report.hostname2.com/Pdf");   
 wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";   
 wr.ContentLength = bytt.Length;   
 wr.Method = "POST";   
 Stream st = wr.GetRequestStream();   
 st.Write(bytt, 0, bytt.Length);   
 st.Close();

Did you see this my job?

Comment: What is this? Do you have a question? Please update your original question to post code examples. They are unreadable in the comments section. What's the problem with the code you have shown? This should work.

Comment: You could use a WebClient as shown in my answer. It will simplify your code and allow you to POST data to the remote site.

Comment: Great. I'll try it now and I will return to you. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
Said method took care of my problem.